# How to train a bounding box detection model?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, mxnet-format

Apparently, this still isn't possible in v12?

I'd like to add a new class to one of the standard object detection architectures. Consider the YOLO v2 detector from the [Neural Net Repo](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/NeuralNetRepository/resources/YOLO-V2-Trained-on-MS-COCO-Data_1).

```
NetModel["YOLO V2 Trained on MS-COCO Data"]
```

Which currently has 80 classes:

```
labels = {"person", "bicycle", "car", "motorcycle", "airplane", "bus",
    "train", "truck", "boat", "traffic light", "fire hydrant", 
   "stop sign", "parking meter", "bench", "bird", "cat", "dog", 
   "horse", "sheep", "cow", "elephant", "bear", "zebra", "giraffe", 
   "backpack", "umbrella", "handbag", "tie", "suitcase", "frisbee", 
   "skis", "snowboard", "sports ball", "kite", "baseball bat", 
   "baseball glove", "skateboard", "surfboard", "tennis racket", 
   "bottle", "wine glass", "cup", "fork", "knife", "spoon", "bowl", 
   "banana", "apple", "sandwich", "orange", "broccoli", "carrot", 
   "hot dog", "pizza", "donut", "cake", "chair", "couch", 
   "potted plant", "bed", "dining table", "toilet", "tv", "laptop", 
   "mouse", "remote", "keyboard", "cell phone", "microwave", "oven", 
   "toaster", "sink", "refrigerator", "book", "clock", "vase", 
   "scissors", "teddy bear", "hair drier", "toothbrush"};
```

As a minimal workable example, here is a toy set of training data for an additional class 'Fish', consisting of image and bounding-box coordinate pairs:

```
{fish, bboxes} = 
  CloudGet @ CloudObject[
   "https://www.wolframcloud.com/objects/9c57ab39-52e2-40d3-84e6-80c9ee9a42a4"];
HighlightImage[fish[[1]], Rectangle @@ bboxes[[1]]]
```

[image]

Unfortunately, I can't find any information on the training net:

[image]

If I have to, I can download the original training data:

[image]

I also looked on the community but couldn't find any guidance for `NetTrain`'ing bounding box detection networks.

**References:**

- https://pjreddie.com/media/files/papers/YOLOv3.pdf
- https://blog.wolfram.com/2018/12/06/deep-learning-and-computer-vision-converting-models-for-the-wolfram-neural-net-repository/

Comment: I can change the to allow for any architecture, Yolo v2 is actually old anyway.

Comment: @C.E. And it is always possible that someone else on SE knows or a developer might be about to answer with a short tutorial.

Comment: I agree, this is another case where it's frustrating there is no example in the documentation! I believe this network was trained elsewhere and then imported to WL, but I have no evidence to back it up.

Comment: I and a colleague have been working on implementing the training version of the Yolo 2 for a while (it's a complicated loss function) but haven't successfully got NetTrain to run, a divergence error arises. I have been in contact with WRI about the error but not solution yet. It was mentioned in passing by them that the weights were imported rather than training the net in MMA . If anyone is interested in comparing notes on building the training version of Yolo 2 I'd be open to sharing what we've done so far.

Comment: @EstabanW Thanks for sharing, that confirms my fears!

Comment: @M.R. I'm going to wait for version 12 to be released (imminent I think) and test our training version of Yolo 2 on that. I would consider posting the code on Github if there's interest from others in it, interested?

Comment: @EstabanW sure thanks I’ll take a look

Comment: @EstabanW now that v12 is out can you post a link to your failed model?

Comment: Who wants 200pts!?

Comment: Any updates on this?

Comment: @user5601 I know I arrive a little bit late here, but I needed a simplified version of this (just 1 anchor and 1 class) for my [Wolfram Summer School project](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/2029803) and made the loss for it, since didn’t manage to find anything similar elsewhere either. I believe it shouldn’t be too complicated to build the loss for the full net from there. Just in case anybody could happen to find it useful there's a reader-friendly attached notebook at the end of the linked post

Comment: @EstabanW I had a similar problem and was related to incorrectly computing the magnitudes of the coordinates in the loss function as specified in the original paper

Comment: This stuff was table stakes 8 years ago, today it’s still tricky and unsupported in WL

Comment: @abcd version 12.2 should have much better support for training nets, the new FunctionLayer should make complex loss functions and the like far easier to write, Hopefully it will be released soon.