# How to train custom objects using YOLO in Mathematica?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks

I want to train few custom object using YOLO V2 architecture but not sure how to do this. I know that with the NetTake and NetReplace, this is achievable. Can someone point out me in the right direction?

Comment: This is a specific instance of a more general question that asks about *training* a bounding box detection model from scratch (a task for which no example exists):  https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/194120/how-to-train-a-bounding-box-detection-model